# How do i show a cell total based on the month?

Tags: excel

I am having problems with a KPI dashboard function.

I have cell A1 showing the current month `=TEXT(TODAY(),"MMMM")`

In B1:B12 I have the months of the year listed and along side (C1:C12) I have monetary values which auto update based on `=SUMIF` and date range formulas.

I would like cell A2 (Beneath the current month) to show a figure in the range of C1:C12 dependant upon what month it is.

E.g
If the date is any day in January the A1 will show January. A2 will show the figure in C1 next to  January in B1.

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

Comment: SUMIF() which you seem to have used already.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing. Do you want something like that?

[image]

if yes you could try:

`=VLOOKUP($A$1,$B$1:$C$12,2,0)`

Comment: Fantastic! that worked perfectly. Apologies if it was a simple solution I am getting day by day.

Comment: @Alexowen is this was the answer, please vote the as an answer to help others with the same question.